# SPOJ Problem KPRIMES2

Tags: c++, algorithm, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I am new to this forum and not well aware of protocols of this forum so pardon me for my ignorance. My question is related to spoj problem https://www.spoj.pl/problems/KPRIMES2/. I am getting TIME LIMIT EXCEED for this problem.I think the bottleneck of this program is generating 10^9.Could some one suggest how to improve this sieve , faster way to generate prime or how to solve this problem. Here is sketch of my algorithm

This program  generates all the primes of form 2k+1 and encoded these primes into 32 bit integers of array a[i] in which unset bit represents primes.a[0] encodes 3,5,7.......65.a[1] encodes 67 onwards and so on. I have taken a auxiliary array bitcnt[] , in which bitcnt[i] stores sum of unset bits of a[0], a[1],.........a[i]. I used bitcnt for binary search and find the position of kth number.Here is bit explanation of functions.
prime() function generated primes and i encoded the primes onto bits of number[32 bit unsigned integer]. bitcnt array stores sum of unset bits of array a for binary search purpose.
bsearchupper(int m) return index of bitcnt in which m lie. 
Finally in main function , i am storing how many primes are upto upperbound of m and started decreasing value till i got K. Thank you.

Edit:Problem statement from SPOJ

Input

An integer stating the number of queries Q(equal to 100000), and Q lines follow, each containing one integer K between 1 and 50000000 inclusive.

Output

Q lines with the answer of each query: the Kth prime number.

Example

Input:
8
1
10
100
1000
10000
100000
1000000
10000000

Output:
2
29
541
7919
104729
1299709
15485863
179424673

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cmath>
#include<ctime>
#define Lim 1000000000
using namespace std;
unsigned int a[(Lim>>6)+10],bitcnt[(Lim>>6)+10];
int bound;
void prime()
{

    int p_1,q_1,p_2,q_2,Ub=sqrt(Lim*1.0);
    for(int i=3;i<=Ub;i+=2)
    {
            p_1=(i-3)>>6,q_1=((i-3)>>1)&31; 
            if(!(a[p_1] & (1L<<q_1))) 
            for(int j=i*i;j<Lim;j+=i) 
               if(j&1) 
                {
                p_2=(j-3)>>6,q_2=((j-3)>>1)&31;
                a[p_2]|=(1L<<q_2);
                }
    }

    int cnt=0;bound=0;
    for(int i=0; i<=((Lim>>6)-1);i++) 
     {
        //p_1=(i-3)>>6,q_1=((i-3)>>1)&31;
        cnt+=__builtin_popcount(~a[i]);
        bitcnt[bound++]=cnt;
        //cout<<bound-1<<"---"<<bitcnt[bound-1]<<endl;
    }
    //cout<<cnt<<endl;
}
    int bsearchupper(int m)
{
    int lo=0,hi=bound,mid;
    while(lo<hi)
    {
        mid=lo+((hi-lo)>>1);
        if(bitcnt[mid]<=m)lo=mid+1;
        else hi=mid;

    }
    //cout<<"lo= "<<lo<<" mid= "<<mid<<" hi= "<<hi<<endl;
    return lo;
}
    int main()
{
    //clock_t start,end;
    //start=clock();
    prime();
    int t,k,c,ret,w;
    for(scanf("%d",&t);t>0;t--) 
    {
        scanf("%d",&k);
        if(k==1) {cout<<"2"<<endl;continue;}
        k=k-2;
        c=bsearchupper(k);
        ret=bitcnt[c],w=32*(c+1);
        for(int i=31;i>=0;i--)
        {

            if(!(a[c] & (1L<<i))) 
             {
                ret--;
                if(ret==k) printf("%d\n",3+(w-1)*2);

             }
            w--;
        }   
    }

    //end=clock();
            //cout<<((end-start)/(double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC)<<endl; 
}
```

Comment: The one "protocol" oriented advice I'd give is to summarize enough of the problem you're trying to solve that (for example) if SPOJ happened to be offline when somebody read this, they'd still be able to understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider compacting your prime storage even more. For example, in every block of 2*3*5*7*11=2310, there are exactly 1*2*4*6*10=480 numbers that have no prime factor of 11 or less, which you can pack into 15 array entries rather than (about) 36. That will eliminate a few hundred million bit operations sieving out those small factors. You'll have to change your indexing into the bit array; a couple of constant arrays of length 2310 giving the bit index (if it exists) and array element offset would help here, and a similar array (of length 480) converting bit positions back into values mod 2310.